# opencv thresholding and pytesseract

Tags: python, opencv, python-tesseract

currently I am trying to develop some simple computervision code to read the amount of kills that I have in a call of duty game and save it to an array as an integer. The code is screenshotting my screen every second and using opencv I am thresholding the image and inputting it into pytesseract. Although the numbers stay the same, the background noise changes the image a lot and forces a lot of null inputs.  I am ok if it misses a few inputs but it misses %50 or more of all of the digits. If anyone has any tips on thresholding a single digit image with varying backgrounds, it would be a huge help.

'''

```
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:/Program Files/Tesseract-OCR/tesseract'

pyautogui.screenshot('pictures/Kill.png', region = (1822, 48, 30, 23))

img = cv2.imread('pictures/Kill.png')

img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

ret, thresh1 = cv2.threshold(img, 255, 255, cv2.THRESH_TRUNC)

cv2.imwrite('pictures/killthresh1.png',thresh1)

ret, thresh1 = cv2.threshold(img, 180, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

thresh1 = cv2.bitwise_not(thresh1)

cv2.imwrite('pictures/Killthresh2.png', thresh1)

custom_config = r'-l eng --oem 3 --psm 7 -c 

tessedit_char_whitelist="1234567890" '

killnumber = pytesseract.image_to_string(thresh1, config = custom_config)
```

'''

[Original pyautogui screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wHAy.png)

[TRUNC thresholded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JFwK.png)

[BINARY thresholded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DK0Po.png)

NOTE: These images yieled a 'NULL' result and I dont know why

Comment: Show some of the input character images that fail. Have you tried otsu thresholding?

Answer (score 0):

After you read the image, `img = cv2.imread('pictures/Kill.png')`

Apply `adaptive-threshold` on Original pyautogui screenshot:

[image]

Now read:

```py
txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(thr, config="--psm 7")
print(txt)
```

Result:

```py
3
```

Code:

---

```py
import cv2
import pytesseract

img = cv2.imread("0wHAy.png")
gry = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thr = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gry, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,
                            cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 21, 9)
txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(thr, config="--psm 7")
print(txt)
```